# How to add my own class to a JSP page?

Tags: java, jsp, oop, netbeans

I'm trying to add a Java class to a jsp page but for some reason it's not working.
[image: Error I'm getting]

[image: jsp page]

[image: File hierarchy]

[image: Class itself. The code is fine and without any errors.]

The error I'm getting:

The JSP page
The project hierarchy
the class itself. There are no erros in the class's code.

Comment: Your `test` folder is not in a source folder. It won't be compiled and therefore there won't be a `.class` file.

Comment: @PradeepSimha Improting would be the right word.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis What is the source folder?

Comment: A Java source folder, where you put your `.java` files which will be compiled to `.class` files and be built along with your web app. (I think you are using Netbeans, look into their build/source folders.)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Turned out that netbeans compiled my code when it was under another package, I change the class package name and now it is working. I'm really not sure why.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Now for some reason I can't compile the class, though I've moved it to Test Packages.

Answer (score 0):

Well, turns out that the solution is really simple.
If you're creating a class for your project you need to put the filename.java file inside a new package in the Test Packages folder in your main project.
Here is how it looks after moving the java file -

[image]
This is a solution for Netbeans as far as I tried.
Can't belive it took me hours to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, the **Test Packages** is for testing purposes; one should use the **Source Packages** as shown below:

[image]